# Implement parallel Hash Table expansion (re-sizing a hash table within an OpenMP parallel region)

Tags: c, multithreading, hash, hashtable, openmp

I am trying to implemented the expansion of a Hash table within an OpenMP parallel region. What I want to achieve: Only 1 thread proceeds with the expansion (locks the entire table and updates it), while the remaining threads refrain from updating the table while the expansion is in progress.

My code either deadlocks or as seen below (in the printf statements), is being updated by other threads while the expansion process is ongoing.

Is there a better way to tackling such a problem, or is my approach plain faulty?

Following are a few code snippets:

```
#define WIN_SIZE                        30
#define HASH_TAB_SIZE                   100

omp_lock_t hash_lock;

/* Each key-value pair entry */
typedef struct htable_each_entry
{
        // key comprising of k+1 mer
        char kmer_plus_one[WIN_SIZE_PLUS];

        // value is a linked-list of read_id's
        struct read_info *read_list;

        struct htable_each_entry *hh_next;
        struct htable_each_entry *hh_prev;

} htable_entry;

/* structure for each bucket entry */
typedef struct htable_each_bucket
{
        htable_entry *series;

        // Lock for each bucket entry
        omp_lock_t writelock;

        int count;

} htable_bucket;

/* structure for the Hash table */
typedef struct hash_table_t {
        size_t size;
        htable_bucket *buckets;

} hash_table_t;
```

> ```
>     int main (int argc, char *argv[])
>     {
>          /* Initializing global lock on table */                         
>               omp_init_lock(&hash_lock);
>
>             hash_table_t *my_hash_table = create_hash_table(HASH_TAB_SIZE);
>
>     #pragma omp parallel shared(rd_seq, my_hash_table, hash_lock)
>             {
>                     int i=0;
>
>                     //Populating the hash table
>     #pragma omp for schedule(static) private(i) firstprivate(num_lines) nowait
>                     for (i=0; i<num_lines; i++)
>                     {
>                             Sliding_window(my_hash_table,i);
>                     }
>
>             }
>             double end_t = omp_get_wtime ();
>             printf ("\nTime for populating entries to the hash table: %f\n", (end_t - start_t));
>
>             int num_entries = count_hashtab_entries(my_hash_table);
>             printf("There are %d entries in the Hash table \n", num_entries);
>     }
>
>
>
>     void Sliding_window (hash_table_t *my_hash_table, int idx)
>     {
>             char kmer_plus_1[WIN_SIZE_PLUS];
>             int i=0;
>             Sequence_r r_seq;
>             htable_entry *tag;
>
>             r_seq = rd_seq[idx];
>
>             /* Table is resized when the number of unique entries in the hash table 
>                exceeds half the number of total buckets allocated.
>                Locking table using "hash_lock". Should be executed by 1 thread, whereas the
>                remaining threads should wait and refrain from updating the table, while table
>                expansion process is in progress.
>             */
>
>             omp_set_lock(&hash_lock);
>
>             if (count_hashtab_entries(my_hash_table) >= (my_hash_table->size/2)) {
>
>                  printf("BEFORE EXPAND: entries in hash table: %d Size: %d thread: %d > \n",count_hashtab_entries(my_hash_table),(int)my_hash_table->size, omp_get_thread_num());
>
>                     Expand_hash_table(my_hash_table);
>
>                  printf("AFTER EXPAND: entries in hash table: %d Size: %d thread: %d \n",count_hashtab_entries(my_hash_table),(int)my_hash_table->size, omp_get_thread_num());
>
>             }
>
>             /* Table expansion done, hence releasing the lock. */
>             omp_unset_lock(&hash_lock);
>
>         for(i=0; (r_seq.rlen - i) > WIN_SIZE; i++)
>         {
>                 memcpy(kmer_plus_1,&r_seq.read_data[i],WIN_SIZE+1);
>                 kmer_plus_1[WIN_SIZE+1] = '\0';
>                 htable_entry *entry_returned = NULL;
>
>                 unsigned bucket_id = generate_hash(my_hash_table, kmer_plus_1);
>
>                 // setting a lock on the respective bucket obtained from hashing 
>                 omp_set_lock(&(my_hash_table->buckets[bucket_id].writelock));
>
>                 // Check if key already exists ?
>                 tag = Find_key_exists(my_hash_table, kmer_plus_1, bucket_id, &entry_returned);
>
>                 if (tag != NULL) /* Key already exists */
>                 {
>                         append_read_info(tag, idx, i);
>                 } else {
>                         /* key does not exist, therefore insert in hashtable */
>                         tag =  (htable_entry *) malloc(sizeof( htable_entry ));
>                         strcpy(tag->kmer_plus_one, kmer_plus_1);
>                         tag->read_list = NULL;
>
>                         Insert_key(my_hash_table, tag, bucket_id, entry_returned);
>                         append_read_info(tag, idx, i);
>                 }
>
>                 // release lock on the respective bucket. 
>                 omp_unset_lock(&(my_hash_table->buckets[bucket_id].writelock));
>        }
> }
> ```

OUTPUT:

```
BEFORE EXPAND: entries in hash table: 500094 Size: 1000000 thread: 0 
AFTER EXPAND: entries in hash table: 500115 Size: 2000000 thread: 0
```

(Note: To avoid my post from becoming exceeding long, I have not added the Expand_hash_table procedure. I can update it if need be.)

As seem above the number of entries in the hash table has exceeded while the expansion process was in progress. Which means, inspite of the lock, multiple threads accessed and updated regions of the hash table.

Is there a way I can ensure atomicity during the resizing of the hash table, done within an "OpenMP parallel for" region?

Comment: What happens when you use `#pragma omp critical Expand { Expand_hash_table(my_hash_table); }` instead? Here `Expand` is just a random name for this critical section.

Comment: Adding a critical region, would ensure only 1 thread performs the expansion, but it does not restrict access to the hash table. Other threads, are still updating sections in the hash table during the Insert/Append functions. I want to ensure that at the time Expand_hash_table() is called, no other thread can update any region of the hash table. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I'm not a C/OpenMP expert, I can only prove that this idea is NOT inherently faulty, the same idea is implemented in project https://github.com/giltene/PauselessHashMap and it seems it works.

Comment: The obvious solution would be to have the thread doing the expansion  set all of the bucket locks - which will both prevent other threads from starting writes, and prevent the expansion from taking place while another threads are still writing.

Comment: @JonathanDursi: I thought of that. But what if the thread doing the expansion, encounters a(or multiple) buckets that have already been locked by other threads at the time. I tried the omp_test_lock feature, to test for availability of each bucket lock, but that really slows things down. Any ideas on how to improve upon this?

Comment: @Hello_PG - but the expansion _has_ to wait for those writers to finish anyway; some form of synchronization there is inevitable and indeed desired.  The alternative is to re-structure the synchronization...

Comment: Perhaps you could just use an existing parallel hash table (for instance the parallel hash map in TBB https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/containers_overview/concurrent_hash_map_cls.htm ). I don't think that it requires that you also use TBB for parallelism.